# Problems with migration of Cassandra db on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cassandra, ubuntu-14.04

When I making migration db Cassandra with command:

```
es@es:~/server-new$ rake ks2:migrate_old
```

After this I get error:

```
rake aborted!
SystemStackError: stack level too deep

Tasks: TOP => ks2:migrate_old => ks2:set_keyspace2 => ks2:configure2 => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

When I start command: rake ks2:migrate_old --trace
I get error:

```
** Invoke ks2:migrate_old (first_time)
** Invoke ks2:set_keyspace2 (first_time)
** Invoke ks2:configure2 (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
/home/es/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:183
Tasks: TOP => ks2:migrate_old => ks2:set_keyspace2 => ks2:configure2 => environment
```

How to make migration work?